# Fastest preset for ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My tv doesn't support dts or I am unsure how to enable it,so I need to convert movies from dts to ac3,as I don't have an audio system good enough to be able to see a difference,and it takes some time

I saw that presets affect compression quality?

Like I need them to convert as fast as possible,but I don't want to lose video quality

here is my current command:

```
ffmpeg -i sampletest.mkv -codec copy -acodec ac3 -vsync 1 -async 1 sampletest2.mkv
```

Comment: You say you don't want to lose video quality, but in your first paragraph you talk about DTS and AC3, which are audio codecs. Also, your command copies the video as-is, so there is no quality loss there. What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: if the presets affect "video" quality,not "audio" quality,I don't care about that

Comment: I don't understand. Your question says, "I don't want to lose video quality". Please clarify: are you talking about audio conversion / audio presets only?